# How long should I expect a golf glove to last before wearing out?

Tags: equipment, golf

I currently play with a Nike DuraFeel golf glove on my leading hand. It's practical, it works, and it fits "like a glove" (as in perfectly; not too tight but nothing to spare). Sometimes I'll glove both hands; I usually only do this at the range when I'm hitting bucket after bucket, but usually on the course I need to get in and out of my right pocket for tees, spare balls etc which is more difficult with a glove.

The problem is that this glove currently lasts me maybe three to four rounds and/or range visits before the thumb develops a huge hole, and by the end of the first round played they get pretty stiff so I often relegate them to range use after just one or two rounds. That makes worn-out gloves a bigger money sink equipment-wise than lost balls; I play C-grade recycled balls so each one I lose is only about $.50, and my lost-ball count is much lower in recent times than it had been.

Questions:

- Am I doing something wrong in my grip causing premature wear?
- Would a more expensive glove last longer, or just waste money on "better feel" (for the first round before it stiffens)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong in my grip causing premature wear?

Are you pressing your thumb on the grip of the club as hard as you could? I can see friction playing a factor there.

Otherwise, I would visit a local golf pro and see what s/he has to say about your grip and why your gloves wear prematurely. S/he can do a lot more to help you in person than I can online.

> Would a more expensive glove last longer, or just waste money on "better feel" (for the first round before it stiffens)?

I have used two pairs of gloves, a Nike DuraFeel and a [FootJoy WeatherSof](http://www.footjoy.com/catalog/productview.asp?c=44).

I used the DuraFeel for about two years (approx. 10 rounds and 25 visits to the range). It did get stiff and dirty, but it is still useable (if I wanted to use it today, I could).

For the past two years (same approx.), I have used the WeatherSof. It is the best glove I ever used. It is very breatheable and more durable than the DuraFeel. In fact, it doesn't feel stiff at all after how long I've used it.

Both gloves cost around $10-15 USD. Therefore, I would not recommend purchasing a more expensive glove (unless a local golf pro recommends otherwise).

Comment: Would it change your answer if I said that my driver, 3-wood and gap/sand wedges were bought used with worn grips, and I have not had the chance to regrip them? The clubs I bought new were custom-fit, and all have a soft, slightly tacky wrap-style.

Comment: @KeithS Totally missed this comment. Anyway, if your hands slip as a result of the worn grips during your swing, not only is that dangerous, but that's the only thing I can see, by my experience, that would contribue to your glove wearing out quickly.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are gripping the club to firmly to me. It might be something about your climate as well are you sweating a lot or is it too humid? I have also noticed that your glove needs to dry out properly after play if you just woad it up and through it in your bag then it will get stiff and when you go to play the next round you will possibly rip the glove, sometimes if you rub a little water or spit on the glove to make it a little more pliable this will keep it from ripping. I try to lay mine out flat when I put it in my bag, and it seems to try better that way. Good luck.

Comment: It's Texas. I do lay the glove flat in the pocket of my golf bag, and I've also started taking pains to avoid getting the glove too wet during a round; not handling cold drinks with that hand, for instance, and that does seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the same golf glove for a full season (Mar-Oct). I have used Mizuno, Nike and FootJoy gloves in the past and have managed to get a full year out of them - although the Nike one was the worse for wear by the end of the season.

Considering they are around £10 I would expect them to last a full season of moderate use (for me that's 2/3 rounds per month).

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong in my grip causing premature wear?

In short, yes. (Sorry to be blunt!) I play quite often and had a similar problem with the pad of my left palm in a bad position. This caused me to rub holes within 3-4 rounds with a few range sessions thrown in.

After changing my grip with the assistance of pro, a glove now lasts me several months.